# Using watir-webdriver to set cookies on internet explorer

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cookies, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am trying to set cookies on Internet Explorer from a Cucumber acceptance test.

Here is the first thing that I tried:

```
browser.cookies.add("my.cookie","90",{:path => "/", :expires => expiredTime})
```

Here is the second thing:

```
browser.driver.manage.add_cookie(name:"my.cookie", value:"90", expires:expired_time)
```

Both of these approaches cause the same exception:

```
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDocumentError) Unable to add cookie to page
```

I only get this exception when using Internet Explorer, but not Firefox.

I am using Windows 7, IE 8, 64-bit.

Some of my gems:
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
cucumber (1.2.1)

Thanks in advance for any advice on fixing this issue.

Comment: What does your step look like where you are adding the cookies? Are you adding the cookies immediately after opening the browser?

Comment: No, I am setting the cookies after navigating to a page.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on Win7 / IE9.  I figured out that adding the cookies failed when the page the browser was on had no-cache headers set.  We created an empty page on our server with far-future cache headers, and setting cookies while on that page works.

I do not know which particular header prevents adding cookies.  Since you probably need to move to a different page to set the cookies, it's worth using one with far-future headers to speed up loading.